# wordpress my own custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to make custom fields in WordPress post.

I am a developer and want to create my own custom field. I don't want to use the default custom fields that are available when we install WordPress.  In fact, I want to add radio
buttons and a check box from where I could select them as you can see in the image I attached.

How do I go about this?

[image: this is a demo image]

Comment: i just work on the default custom fields but dont want to work any more on it instead want to create my own as i mentioned but dont know how and from where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything will be done in functions.php.

You have to declare your extra fields (meta boxes). This article will give you all the explanations : http://www.farinspace.com/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-meta-box/

It should give you all the info you need to add meta boxes (see also : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box)